# Entity Framework - Many to Many relationship and no inheritance.

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I did some searching around and cannot find anything that looks like what I'm trying to do. Here's my situation/problem:

I'm implementing an access control system for a small asp.net MVC application and I want to be able to attach entities (of different types) to a 'security group'. The different entity types all use a GUID primary key and thus their IDs should be unique between tables.

I'll try and provide a pared-down version of my model:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IGroupable> Members { get; set; }
}

public enum EntityKind
{
    User = 10,
    Resource = 15,
}

public interface IGroupable
{
    Guid Id { get; }
    EntityKind Kind { get; }
    ICollection<Group> MemberOf { get; }
}

public class User : IGroupable
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EntityKind Kind { get { return EntityKind.User; } }
    public ICollection<Group> MemberOf { get; set; }

    Guid IGroupable.Id
    {
        get { return this.UserId; }
    }
}

public class Resource : IGroupable
{
    public Guid ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public EntityKind Kind { get { return EntityKind.Resource; } }
    public ICollection<Group> MemberOf { get; set; }

    Guid IGroupable.Id { get { return this.ResourceId; } }
}
```

I am stuck as to how I configure entity framework to handle this type of relationship. Note that 'User' and 'Resource' don't share a base class, only an interface. I'd like to avoid using any type of inheritance for this as I'm concerned about performance.

Comment: one user can be assigned to many groups? or a user can have only one group?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "this type of relationship" is?

Comment: It's a many:many relationship. Each group can contain multiple entities, and each entity may be added to multiple groups. There are other entity types that aren't featured in the example code.

Comment: ok. do you know what is entity mapping in code first EF?

Comment: I do, but I'm not sure how to apply mapping to this situation.

@Rob, "this type of relationship" as in, one where the child side of the relationship can contain entities of different types... not sure how to describe it any more clearly than that.

At this point my only alternative that I know will work is to create  separate navigation properties in Group for each type of entity, which will get ugly and become a maintainability nightmare, I think.

Comment: Does `Group` need to have a `Members` navigation property? You could implement the relationship as uni-directional rather than bi-directional.